# How can I remove from first select multiple and add to second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two select multiple menu, and I wish to addthe value to second and remove at the sam time from the first when I click "Add", and it can return the value to the first and remove form second when I click "delete".

[image]

I have draft the coding below.

```js
const btnAdd    = document.querySelector('#btnAdd');
const btnRemove = document.querySelector('#btnRemove');
const listbox   = document.querySelector('#list');
const framework = document.querySelector('#framework');

btnAdd.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // validate the option
  if (framework.value == '') {
    alert('Please select at least one class.');
    return;
  }
  // create a new option
  const option = new Option(framework.value, framework.value);
  // add it to the list
  listbox.add(option, undefined);

  // remove all selected option
  let index = framework.options.length;
  while (index--) {
    if (selected[index]) {
      framework.remove(index);
    }
  }

  // reset the value of the input
  framework.value = '';
  framework.focus();
};

// remove selected option
btnRemove.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // save the selected options
  let selected = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < listbox.options.length; i++) {
    selected[i] = listbox.options[i].selected;
  }

  // remove all selected option
  let index = listbox.options.length;
  while (index--) {
    if (selected[index]) {
      listbox.remove(index);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <label for="framework">Framework:</label>
    <select id="framework" name="framework" multiple>
      <option value="1A">1A</option>
      <option value="1B">1B</option>
      <option value="1C">1C</option>
      <option value="2A">2A</option>
      <option value="2B">2B</option>
      <option value="2C">2C</option>
      <option value="3A">3A</option>
      <option value="3B">3B</option>
      <option value="3C">3C</option>
      <option value="3D">3D</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btnAdd">Add</button>

    <label for="list">Framework List:</label>
    <select id="list" name="list" multiple>

    </select>
    <button id="btnRemove">Remove Selected Framework</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have draft the coding but it seems failed.

Comment: it's seems this code need some css...

Answer (score 1):

simply do that this way :

there is no need to delete (or create) anything, just re-affect option to it new select parent.

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');

myForm.onsubmit = e => e.preventDefault(); // disable submit on testing implemention

myForm.onclick = ({target : btn}) =>
  {
  if (!btn.matches('button[data-mov]')) return

  let sel_out = (btn.dataset.mov === 'add') ? myForm.framework : myForm.list;
  let sel_in  = (btn.dataset.mov === 'del') ? myForm.framework : myForm.list;
    ;
  if (sel_out.selectedOptions.length===0) alert('no option selected...!');
  
  [...sel_out.selectedOptions].forEach( opt => sel_in.add( opt ));
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
#my-form label {
  display        : inline-block;
  vertical-align : middle;
  }
#my-form select {
  display   : block;
  width     : 6rem;
  height    : 20rem;
  font-size : 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  }
button {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label>
    Framework:
    <select name="framework" multiple>
      <option value="1A">1A</option>
      <option value="1B">1B</option>
      <option value="1C">1C</option>
      <option value="2A">2A</option>
      <option value="2B">2B</option>
      <option value="2C">2C</option>
      <option value="3A">3A</option>
      <option value="3B">3B</option>
      <option value="3C">3C</option>
      <option value="3D">3D</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <button data-mov="add"> >>> </button>
    <button data-mov="del"> <<< </button>
  </label>
  <label>
    List:
    <select name="list" multiple></select>
  </label>
</form>
```